# Improve Node w/ Express Websocket Ping?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I'm working on a game where you scan a QR code on a TV, which loads the controller on your phone and passes off player actions via websocket. Functionally, it's just passing off the value of a range slider to the TV to represent the player's Y axis coordinate.

I'm running into an issue where the response time isn't great. Around a 200ms delay between the action and reaction.

I'm using node with express, and the socket.io library. I'm on a budget Digital Ocean server with the one-click node.js install, and already set the region as close to my physical location as possible.

While I can't share the actual link due to the nature of the assignment, the code handling communication is below:

**App.js:**

```
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server, { wsEngine: 'ws' });

app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.io = io;
  next();
});

app.get('/move/:id/:pos', function(req, res, next) {
  res.io.emit("move", {id: req.params.id, pos: req.params.pos});
  res.send('move player');
});
```

**Controls.js:**

```
function connectSocket(){
  //Browser compatibility check
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    try {
      req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (e) {
      try {
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      catch (e) {}
    }
  }
  req = new XMLHttpRequest();
}

function startGame(){
  connectSocket();
  req.open("GET", "start/"+myID, true);
  req.send(null);
  controlLoop = setInterval(function(){
    movePlayer(mySlider.value);
  }, 20);
}

let lastPos = 0;
function movePlayer(myPos){
  if(myPos != lastPos){
    req.open("GET", "move/" + myID + "/" + myPos, true);
    req.send(null);
  }
  lastPos = myPos;
}
```

**Gameplay.js:**

```
socket.on('move', function(data){
  if(data.id == myID){
    myPlayer.style.top = (data.pos/100)*(window.outerHeight - 300) + 'px';
  }
});
```

Any help in how I can speed up the response time would be appreciated! This is my first experiment with websockets, needing low ping might have been biting off more than I can chew :)

Comment: Is the budget Digital Ocean server running your process all the time or does it get swapped out? Does a 2nd data packet sent right after the first have a similar delay?  If you just `ping` your server from the command line, how long is that response time.  You need to sort out how much of this is just network latency and how much of it is server latency.  Can you run a client on the same host as your server and see what it's latency is (this would remove any network latency and only show server latency).

Comment: Appreciate the tips! Pinging the server directly is only ~18ms. The data is passed off on a 20ms interval, which I've experimented with (going up to 50) without any luck. The server is running the process all the time.

Comment: OK, I guess you've proven you have a slow server and it isn't mostly a network issue.  Do you know how the same code responds if you run it on localhost?  The question is aimed at figuring out if this is an issue with running on Digital Ocean or an issue with your server code, independent of where it's running?  As you can see, this is just a process of trying to narrow down the problem to see where most of the delay is so you can eventually develop theories that you design experiments to test.

Comment: Absolutely, appreciate the guidance! I've just been looking for a good cheap node server and I haven't needed to worry about ping before. It doesn't have a delay at all running locally.

Comment: Then, I'd suggest you start a support incident with Digital Ocean, explain what you measured and that it appears to just be the responsiveness of their server that is an issue.  I'm not suggesting that they will magically fix it because of a support contact, but it will likely be informative to hear what they say and whether they attribute it to the budget level of account or not.

Comment: I did that, they said they aren't a good service for these kinds of requests. So problem solved, I guess! Now I just need to find a good host for extremely small scale online gaming :)

Comment: Interesting.  I guess you got your answer.  I'd be curious what alternative you find that's better.

Comment: I actually managed to get it working decently without moving hosts - I did switch from a shared to dedicated droplet, which improved performance to some degree, but the big shortfall was that I was not re-firing the connectSocket function with each call! I figured I only needed to do it up front and not with every request.

Comment: I can't imagine you need all that stuff in `connectSocket()` any more unless you're trying to support really, really old browsers.  Just use `var req = new XMLHttpRequest();` right in your `startGame()` and `movePlayer()` functions.  Every function call should have it's own `req` anyway - you shouldn't be sharing globally.

Comment: Appreciate the tips! I was following a very basic tutorial that was a few years old, makes sense that it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know each call needed its own XMLHttp request, was using a global one - thanks jfriend00 for the guidance!